# Would tag metrics be useful?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, community, metrics

Sometimes it seems I'm asking unanswerable questions or at least ones whose answers I can't just *accept*. I'm willing to bet this happens to others, not just with popular technologies, but even with mature or declining technologies (Or subjects if we extend this to all of StackExhange). Would it be useful to the community to add metrics that measure a tag's or tags' current percent of accepted answers, rate of decay of accepted answers, rate of answer (e.g. time-to-first, rate) and so on? Or would it be detrimental? I can see positives and negatives: "oh, no one can answer X but I know a lot about it" or "no one can answer X, so why ask?". Or, 50 answers wrt tag X in Y minutes provides a Zeitgeist of Z. It seems useful in trying to judge whether my interests or questions fall along the lines of others or whether I'm an outlier. Thoughts?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166653/competitiveness-of-various-tags-on-stackoverflow